How can I make my Excel add-in appear on iPad without sideloading?
I've developed an Office.js Excel add-in which has recently been deployed by my organisation through Integrated Apps. The add-in works perfectly on MacOS and through the browser, but I would like it to be available on iPad. The 'admin-managed' add-in tab only appears on desktop -- it does not appear when I open Office Add-ins on iPad, nor is the add-in in the 'my add-ins' list, even though I'm signed in with my organisation. Sideloading it works well, but I want others to be able to use it without the hassle.
Have tried asking Microsoft Support, and was told "there is no built-in feature in Office on iPad to show admin-managed add-ins nor make the add-in show up in the 'my add-ins' list", but they also mentioned others might have helpful suggestions.
Is there any way I can access the add-in on Excel for iPad without sideloading it? Any help would be much appreciated!
